# How to Change .libPaths() permanently in R?

Tags: r

Whenever I change the library path order using the `.libPaths()` function, it reverts back to the default if I restart R. How can I change this permanently? I am working on a Linux computing cluster (I don't have admin rights) so, I want to add my local library to R permanently.

I have to do this every time I start R

```
.libPaths(c("/home/...","/home...","/local/library"))
```

Comment: Put it in your `.Rprofile`

Comment: oh.. such a simple thought. thanks

Comment: The solution by @JoshuaUlrich does not work for people who do not have administrative rights on their computer.

Comment: @Therkel: that's incorrect. This worked for the OP and they explicitly said they do not have admin rights.  Nothing about putting `.libPaths` in your `.Rprofile` requires admin rights.

Comment: Yes you do not require any admin rights. Just keep the .Rprofile file in your default working directory.

Comment: Every user can edit every file in their default or home directory -- so editing `~/.Rprofile` is a) possible in every installation and b) preferable to copying it around.

Answer (score 20):

For completeness, and as I can't show this in a comment:

1. Default on all Debian and Ubuntu systems with the shipped R package:

   edd@max:~$ R -q -e 'print(.libPaths())'
   R> print(.libPaths())
   [1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
   [3]            "/usr/lib/R/library"
   R>
   R>
2. Which we can alter by modifying `R_LIBS_SITE`:

   edd@max:~$ R_LIBS_SITE="/usr/lib/R/Library" R -q -e 'print(.libPaths())'
   R> print(.libPaths())
   [1] "/usr/lib/R/library"
   R>
   R>
3. But modifying `R_LIBS` does *not* work:

   edd@max:~$ R_LIBS="/usr/lib/R/Library" R -q -e 'print(.libPaths())'
   R> print(.libPaths())
   [1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
   [3]            "/usr/lib/R/library"
   R>
   R>
   edd@max:~$

See `help(Startup)` for the full and detailed treatment. On Debian and Ubuntu we have been setting these three directories as the default for well over a decade.  As it is set via `R_LIBS_SITE` here, this is the variable you need to alter here.  In general, you need to override the variable holding the value and you may not know *ex ante* which one that is.

As for the original answer, on Debian and Ubuntu we use the file `/etc/R/Renviron`.  As `help(Startup)` details, you can set any number of ways to alter this *permanently* for your startup -- and all these points hold for all different OSs:

1. Alter the system files such as `Renviron` or `Renviron.site` *if you have the proper permissions*
2. Else alter the per-user file `~/.Renviron`
3. Alternatively, alter the environment variables `R_LIBS` or `R_LIBS_USER` or `R_LIBS_SITE` at the system level *if you have the proper permissions*
4. Else alter the variables `R_LIBS` or `R_LIBS_USER` or `R_LIBS_SITE` at the user level.
5. Lastly, call `.libPaths(...new path to be added here...)` in your R startup files as e.g. in `.Rprofile`.

Do see `help(Startup)` for a fuller-length discussion.

Comment: Personally, I find `help(Startup)` to be more confusing than helpful in this instance.

Comment: I was not claiming it is easy reading as there are _a lot_ of moving parts to consider, and it does that.  But it is comprehensive.  Which is really all I said.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel can you please refer a similar thing for windows ?Thanks

Comment: I showed R commands, and those are naturally _portable_ across operating systems. If you thought this was only for Linux or macOS you were mistaken.  See `help(.libPaths)` and `help(Startup)` in your R session, and maybe look for some tutorials or blog on "customizing your R environment".  Windows users do it the same way.

Answer (score 10):

find the `Rprofile` file (no dot) in R installation folder

```
find -name Rprofile

#Getting something like:
#lib/R/library/base/R/Rprofile
```

Open the file and search for:

```
invisible(.libPaths(c(unlist(strsplit(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS"), ":")),
                      unlist(strsplit(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), ":") )
                      )))
```

comment other paths and add your desired path

```
invisible(.libPaths(c(#unlist(strsplit(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS"), ":")),
                      #unlist(strsplit(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), ":") )
                      "/home/users/username/R/4.0.1/lib/R/library" # desired path
                      )))
```

This can be useful also: (for `.bashrc` file)

```
export R_LIBS='/home/users/username/R/4.0.1/lib/R/library'
export R_LIBS_USER='/home/users/username/R/4.0.1/lib/R/library'
```

Comment: It is preferable to edit Rprofile.site instead -- it is meant for _site-local_ changes.  This can matter during upgrades.

Answer (score 5):

2 major solutions:

1. In `.Rprofile` you could leave code that sets  `.libPaths()`
2. Just set the appropriate environment variable such as `R_LIBS` in Windows or `R_LIBS_SITE=` in Linux, etc, to whatever you like, e.g.

   ```
    R_LIBS=C:/R/Library
   ```

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel What's the situation where that would be the case? I'm really just quoting stat.ethz.ch

Comment: Any Debian or Ubuntu box.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Oh I explicitly specified Windows

Comment: You can (should, even) also remove the worrds ".. in Windows" up there as your answer is _correct_ without it.

Comment: I didn''t ask you to qualify, just remove the per-OS settings.  **Both OS** will listen to both variables, see `help(Startup)`.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, I find that in a 'fresh' installation there is no user library and packages are all installed in the version-specific system library. Eventually, a user library is created (possibly accidentally or via an RStudio prompt) and is set to the default location for future package installations. So, if you're not paying close attention you end up with some packages installed in the system library and some in the user library.

The user library is listed first and the system library is listed second:

```r
.libPaths()
> [1] "/Users/<username>/Library/R/3.6/library"                         
> [2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library"
```

I like to keep everything in one place (the system library), so to accomplish this (permanently) I do the following:

In a Terminal window, create a `.Rprofile` file in your user directory:

```
nano ~/.Rprofile
```

In that file, add the following line of R code:

```r
.libPaths( c(.libPaths()[2], .libPaths()[1]) )
```

Alternatively, add a similar line of R code but with hardcoded paths:

```r
.libPaths( c("/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library", "/Users/<username>/Library/R/3.6/library") )
```

Replace `<username>` with your actual username.  Then `Ctrl-O` (save) and `Ctrl-X` (exit) that file.

Either line switches the order of the paths listed above, so that path `[2]` (system) is first (Default) and path `[1]` (user) is second.

Importantly, by putting this line of code in your user's `.Rprofile` it will be run every time R starts and you (hopefully) won't have to worry about this again.

Comment: this solution seems to not work as well or at all if you do not have admin permissions on the machine when you open RStudio.