How can I change where R compiles C scripts when installing libraries?
R is using /private/tmp/* to install libraries and compile C scripts. I need to change where that is done because of permission issues on my machine. How can I change this?
I remember there is a solution and I believe it involved setting something in .Renviron, but I cannot find it.
* installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for R_HOME... /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.4.0_1/lib/R
checking for R... /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.4.0_1/lib/R/bin/R
checking for endianness... little
checking for cat... /bin/cat
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/RtmpFvn4n8/R.INSTALL1707236046/stringi':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


Side note: terminology: C is not a scripting language.  There are C "programs" and "libraries", but no C "scripts".

I take the compilation to be done in the context of installing new R packages.  As what user are you doing that?  I ask in part because my experience of the build and installation locations for R packages is not consistent with your description, and because you mention permission issues.

And what command(s) are you using to perform the installation?

@JohnBollinger to install, I'm running install.packages("stringi") from the R console. The compilation is done while installing new R packages. It is trying to compile within /private/tmp, but I have some security on my machine that prevents that from happening in that location (from what I remember).

The documentation for install.packages() speaks at least to the issue of installation location.  You can specify via the lib parameter to install.packages(), and if you don't, then the first element of .libPaths() is used.  You can influence the value of .libPaths() in multiple ways, including at least by environment variable, via code in your .Rprofile, and via manual command.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387660/how-to-change-libpaths-permanently-in-r.

Thanks, but that is not my issue. .libPaths() correctly returns /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.4/site-library. The C compiler running in /private/tmp is the issue.

You're missing the point.  If you want the package to be installed other than in /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.4/site-library, then (just) /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.4/site-library is not correct for you.  You need the intended package installation folder in that path, too, otherwise it will be difficult to use the package.  It would be normal to put a personal R library folder in libPaths() for such a purpose, and moreover to put it first. Something along these lines is what you do if you're going to install packages as yourself.  That or run R under sudo, which I cannot recommend.

Alternatively, you might find (I'm unsure) that Homebrew provides stringi as its own (Homebrew) package, separate from the main R package.  If so, then installing it via brew would be a good way forward that probably puts stringi in site-library.

R uses the TMPDIR environment variable to compile (see R Installation and Administration). My TMPDIR (set in .Renviron) was deleted, so it defaulted to /tmp which was pointing to /private/tmp.
I just created the directory (with executable permissions).
