# R Reset the Path of Libraries

Tags: r, environment-variables, path-variables

I am running Windows 7, and changed one of my path variables which effected where R was installing my packages.  I tried following this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662905/3950745, but accidently set it to a directory for which I don't have proper permissions getting this error:

```
Error installing package: Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library
```

Is there anyway to reset to the default where R installs that packages.  The problem is I never bothered to look where this was earlier, so I can't manually set it back to where it should be.

Thank you!