# Installing Keras for R - reticulate package fails with "Rcpp.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: r, gcc, keras, rcpp

I'm pretty new to R and I'm banging my head against the wall here trying to install Keras for R. Running with R 3.4.1 and 1.0.153 on Windows 10.
I've installed Rcpp and devtools, but when running

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
```

it fails when attempting to install the reticulate package

```
* installing *source* package 'reticulate' ...
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/Users/danlin/R341/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"\\Mac/Home/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:0:
reticulate_types.h:7:18: fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Rcpp.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/Users/danlin/R341/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/danlin/R341/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="reticulate.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RcppExports.o event_loop.o libpython.o python.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'reticulate'
```

One thing that strikes me as odd is the include directives to g++, especially

```
-I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"
```

I have no idea where it got this path, but is't certainly nothing that exist on my local machine.

I've tried reinstalling both R and RStudio, but to no avail.
Any ideas on how to move forward?

Comment: maybe try to install Rcpp package ? `install.package("Rcpp")`

Comment: Did you read the second line of the post? :-)

Comment: Sorry didn't see. Then maybe check if there is not a problem with the version

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue; After reading this post I realized that the UNC path is the problem: [How do I change the default library path for R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages) 
In Rstudio, when running

```
.libPaths()
```

I got back two results

```
[1] "\\\\Mac/Home/Documents/R/win-library"
[2] "C:/Users/danlin/R341/library"
>
```

There seems to be a number of ways to fix this, but what I did was edit the Rprofile.site (found in RHOME/etc) to contain

```
.libPaths("C:\Users\danlin\R341\library")
```

Comment: In general, R support for UNC paths is flaky. I'd create a network drive shortcut to \\Mac and use that for everything.

Comment: Good catch. I think that is more or less a FAQ for R use, and has little to do with Rcpp, reticulate or keras.

Comment: Absolutely, it was just a coincidence that showed up when installing Keras.