# How to use R Server version in Jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter, r-server

I'm using R Server for the `rxGlm` functionality, but I don't like rstudio. How can I use this version of R in Jupyter. I've tried all of the options found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages) ad nauseum. Has anyone else figured this out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rserver is available with Jupyter. All you can do is install the R Kernel for Jupyter.

Here is the list of kernels available for Jupyter notebook:
https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels

To install the R Kernel, follow the steps here:
https://irkernel.github.io/installation/
or here:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/jupyter-notebook-r