# R_LIBS_USER and windows shared folder network path

Tags: r

I've been using Renviron.site to set the R_LIBS_USER path.
Now I'd like to share this same folder across several machines so I don't have to maintain multiple sources of packages. I shared a folder using windows SMB and I'm trying the code here:

```
R_LIBS_USER="//sw20comp02-d/library"
```

I've tried several variations and they don't work. Here are some:

```
R_LIBS_USER=//sw20comp02-d/library
R_LIBS_USER=\\\\sw20comp02-d\\library
R_LIBS_USER="//sw20comp02-d/library"
R_LIBS_USER="\\\\sw20comp02-d\\library"
```

I've found examples where people have similar paths listed, but for some reason it's not working for me.

eg. [How do I change the default library path for R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages)

Comment: Setting it manually via the R command line works if I used the local folder name "D:/R/library" but not the network name. The network name does work in windows explorer.

Comment: Ok, in case this saves people time. It worked when I shared one folder level deeper.

Comment: What does `.libPaths()` return after you start R with this variable set?

Comment: > .libPaths()
[1] "\\\\SW20comp2-d/R/library"          "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.2/library"     Sharing the library folder in windows did not work for some reason, however when I instead shared the R folder, then the R_LIBS_USER parameter started working.

Comment: Does `list.files(.libPaths()[1])` show the packages? What about `list.files("\\\\sw20comp02-d\\library")`? What ever version works in list.files would be the version you need to show up in `.libPaths()`.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, yes list.files(.libPaths()[1]) works. To be clear: I've solved the problem and it wasn't with the format of the string as listed in the original question. It was with which folder windows share was set up on. If I share the R folder it works. If I share the R/library folder, it does not. The format of the R_LIBS_USER parameter was a separate question. Thanks for your help though!