# R packages installation directory problem

Tags: r, directory, installation, package, default

I changed the default directory of the packages installation using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39056424/7769755) answer. However, when I try to use ggplot2 appears the following message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
>    number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could it actually be an issue with your data size (number of columns and matrices dont match)? Rather than the package