# Installing Rcmdr in R 4 fails

Tags: install.packages

I installed R 4 in an MX Linux 19.3 (XFCE) laptop, and it works fine, including Rstudio.  However, attempts to install Rcmdr (install.packages("Rcmdr", dependencies=TRUE) failed, producing a list of errors about unavailable packages, etc.
I tried several repositories, but all produced the same disappointing result.  Previously, I used Rcmdr with R 3.5 and 3.6, so I sort of thought I knew how to do it-- until now.
Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: If you could post the specific error output you get, it would help us help you! Even if it seems like a lot of text, sometimes the package that caused the problem is way back on the command line. Some packages rely on a variety of non-R libraries that need to be installed before the R package that wraps that binary can be installed. Tracking down the specific ones you need can depend on your setup.

Comment: Also, a tip is to restart your R session (Ctrl+Shift+F10 in Rstudio) to unload any packages that may be currently loaded. Some packages are used by Rstudio itself and I find that I have to install from the regular terminal.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I had installed many missing packages outside R, but it still does not work.
I see many instances of:
Error: package ‘XXX’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
Is there a way to tell R/Rstudio to re-install all those packages that need to be re-installed?  Otherwise, I shall never finish re-installing all those nested dependencies.

Comment: Ooh. That is a very interesting piece of information that would have been evident if you had edited your post to add the console log. It sounds like your R library path is messed up and is directed at a folder containing 3.x.x installed packages.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages/42643674

Comment: Thanks for your help-- I suspect you are right about the old version contamination-- it looks like R 4 was being installed in the same folder as 3.5 and 3.6.  I removed those, but I am still getting the error.  
I tried to post the console output, but stackOverflow has some draconian rules about the acceptable format for such pastes, which it considers "code" that must be formatted properly, and I gave up on that after a few attempts.  I did nothing about setting up the Library-- I just left everything as default.  In R 3.5 or 3.6 I had no such problems.

Comment: I would delete your library folder. Most library paths returned by `.libPaths()` should have a version-specific subfolder. But you could have a setup with a local library where all of your R installations are dumping their installations into. If you have multiple versions of R installed, might be best to cull them and make sure your $PATH is set up to use the correct one from command line, etc.

Comment: I have now removed the old versions and made sure that the PATH points to the correct location where R 4 files are, but the problem persists-- it seems to gag on ggplot2.

Comment: Getting rid of the library-site in /usr/local/lib/R and reinstalling solved the problem.  It shouldn't be that hard, but I am ignorant...

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the library-site in /usr/local/lib/R and reinstalling Rcmdr solved the problem.  It shouldn't be that hard, but I am ignorant...