# unable to install package in R Studio because file is not writeable

Tags: r

I am facing a problem while trying to install packages in Rstudio.

For example, I face this error when I try to install devtools:

`> install.packages("devtools")`

```
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages : unable to install packages
```

Any suggestions about what should I do?

Comment: Usually it would prompt you to create a personal (user-specific) library. Did you get no such message? That's not where you usually install package unless you were running as administrator or something. What version of R are you running and on what OS version? What does `.libPaths()` return?

Comment: Whether it prompted you or not, I recommend you create a directory for this use. On windows, it should default to looking for (and using, if found) `HOME/R/win-library/x.y` (where HOME is often either `c:/Users/yourname/Documents/` or just `c:/Users/yourname/`; and `x.y` are the major/minor versions of R). For instance, on mine, it's `C:/Users/r2/R/win-library/4.0` (I have R-4.0.3). If that directory does not exist, then created it, restart RStudio and/or R, and then re-attempt to install the package(s) you need.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for your reply...I am getting a message about creating a personal library but when I confirm I face the following problem/error

`Warning in install.packages :
  cannot create dir 'C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\???????', reason 'Invalid argument'
Error in install.packages : unable to create ‘C:/Users/giorg/OneDrive/???????/R/win-library/4.0’ `...................

`.libPaths()` returns:

`"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"`

Comment: It seems you are using OneDrive which is likely causing the problem. Maybe this guide can help: https://medium.com/@ValidScience/how-to-fix-rstudios-package-installation-on-windows-10-c1e602bf3a1f or this possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643674/2372064

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you very much for your help, problem solved!

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your reply and your time!