# set R_USER for multiple users under windows

Tags: r, startup

Windows seems to put R libraries in a onedrive directory by default if onedrive is in use. This is undesirable especially if you're using both R and onedrive on multiple computers with the same onedrive account.

How would I set my library to be put inside of C:\users<username>\documents instead of in C:\users<username>\onedrive\documents?  There are good solutions here ([How do I change the default library path for R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages)), but they're mostly focused on solving this for a single windows account. Is there a general way to solve it for all accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Every R installation has an `etc/` directory with configuration, in it you can set `Rprofile.site` or, easier still, `Renviron.site`.

Files ending in `.site` should not get overwritten on the next install. Make sure you don't bulk delete though.

You can query where it is via `R.home("etc")`. On my (Linux) system:

```
> R.home("etc")
[1] "/usr/lib/R/etc"
>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk! I was self-documenting the same solution but you were too fast!

Answer (score 0):

Really excellent solution from here (https://github.com/r-windows/docs/issues/3):

just create an Renviron.site file in the /etc folder of your Rinstallation, then copy the following line to it:

```
R_USER=C:/Users/${USERNAME}/Documents
```

This sets R_USER which in turn sets R_LIBS_USER according to the user directory of each account under windows 10.