# Rstudio - tzdb package "failed to read package metada"

Tags: r, rstudio

Having trouble running code using tidyverse and readr packages because of issues that come down to the tzdb package.

When I go into my windows explorer location of my R library and try to delete the package manually there, I'm unable to. When I click into the tzdb package folder and try to click on the "Meta" folder, I get the error message "The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid".

Then, when I try to uninstall/remove from within Rstudio, I get the error message "there is no package called tzdb"...despite the package showing up in the Packages view window. Also of note, when looking at the package in the package view window, the description for it is "[Failed to read package metadata]"

I've checked my CRAN mirror and deleted and reinstalled both R and Rstudio, and still having these issues.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas or thoughts! Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes R/RStudio might not have permissions to access files in certain locations - you could try running RStudio "as an administrator" and see if that helps.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you're unable to delete the package manually from the windows explorer location?

Comment: When I google your error *"The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid"*, I get a bunch of results mentioning OneDrive. I would strongly recommend configuring R so that your package library is in a plain local folder, not in OneDrive. You can find info on changing your library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31707941/903061).

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this community post, where I also suggested that OneDrive should be avoided. https://community.rstudio.com/t/readr-loading-error-help/127953