# Where should I put my R personal library

Tags: r

First I should say that I have a ssd and a hdd.  I'm trying to install a package in R 3.2.2 and getting the "Would you like to use a personal library instead" message.  The problem is that when I say yes, the default directory is on my hdd, even though R is installed on the ssd.  Is this supposed to happen or should I change the directory?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work/15170774?s=1|2.1455#15170774

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  I'm wondering more about where to create the library instead of how.  Thank you though.

Comment: Generally the loading of packages is not the bottleneck. Access to the data is more typically the determinant of efficiency. So unless you package has a ton of data, say one of those genomic databases or some really complex map, it probably will not matter.

Comment: Can you explain this?  Wouldn't I have access to the data either way?

Comment: R and its packages get loaded into memory. It's calculations are in memory. The slow stuff is loading large datasets and saving results. Loading-data--from and saving-to SSDs would be expected to improve "throughput". If you save intermediate values into an .Rdata file which by default goes to your working directory, that should be on the fastest drive available.

Comment: So regardless of which drive I put the library on it is loaded into memory either way