# I am unable to install packages in R

Tags: r, package, installation

When I try to install any package in Rstudio I get the following error message:

```
Error in install.packages : path[1]="C:\Users\javad\Documents\.Rhistory\win-library\3.2": The system cannot find the path specified
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the file `.Rhistory` in directory `C:\Users\javad\Documents\.Rhistory`

Now try installing the package. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your library path to a folder that exists.

At the shell prompt type:

```
   export R_LIBS="C:/users/your_username/R_libs"
   mkdir C:/users/your_username/R_libs
```

[Changing R default library path using .libPaths in Rprofile.site fails to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work)

https://www.stat.osu.edu/computer-support/mathstatistics-packages/installing-r-libraries-locally-your-home-directory

Answer (score 1):

In my case antivirus which was stopping r studio to download and install.
For that we can either add exception in antivirus for r studio or disable antivirus and install.