# How to properly set up the library directory/path in R

Tags: r

My goal is to define a single path which `R` will use for installing and searching for libraries. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) that this can be done by changing the `Rprofile.site` file in the `R` installation path. I tried two commands there:

```
.libPaths("D:/RLibrary")
.Library.site <- file.path("D:/RLibrary")
```

of which I do not fully understand the difference even after reading the help files.

However after starting `R`, libraries are still looked for in two locations.

```
.libPaths()
[1] "D:/RLibrary"                        "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library"
```

Why is this, and how do I change the library path to my desired path only?

Comment: Changing to your desired path only is probably not a good idea, because some of R's default packages seem to work for me only when in the default folder. But your "D:/RLibrary" folder should now be the first place that it looks for packages, which should take care of things for you.

Comment: Maybe try packrat? that will create a local project directory... which gets around a lot of the nasty library confusion issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest you don't want a **single** directory for packages, since a number of base packages come with R. Instead you want a single directory where a user will install packages.

Create a `.Renviron` file and add the environment variable `R_LIBS` pointing to the directory you want your packages to end up in. On my machine, I have

```
# Linux 
R_LIBS=/data/Rpackages/
```

Or if you have Windows something like

```
# Windows
R_LIBS=C:/R/library
```

Your `.libPaths()` would now look something like

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/data/Rpackages"   "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
```

This means that when I install a package it goes to `/data/ncsg3/Rpackages`

---

If you really want to only have a single directory, you can set the `R_LIBS_SITE` variable to omit the default directories.

Comment: I am confused. What is the difference to the `Rprofile.site`?

Comment: See https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/set-up.html  - Renviron is for environment variables.

Comment: Note that for this to work, `$R_LIBS` needs to exist beforehand. Running `mkdir -p $R_LIBS` (on Linux, anyway) should do that.

Comment: @csgillespie can you add more directories to `R_LIBS=` using a colon? I know this can be done in `.libPaths()`