# how to fix the warning error saying installation path not writeable?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I want to update bioconductor version 3.9 on R 3.6.0 , but I am getting an error message "installation path is not writeable"

I have tried the same with an older version of R 3.2.4 and it was given me the same error messsage.

here I wanted to update and this is what I have

```
update.packages()
```

```
Warning: package 'boot' in library '/usr/lib/R/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'MASS' in library '/usr/lib/R/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'survival' in library '/usr/lib/R/library' will not be updated
cluster :
 Version 2.0.8 installed in /usr/lib/R/library 
 Version 2.0.9 available at https://cloud.r-project.org
Update? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

```
 y
```

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpzyzblW/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  installation of package ‘cluster’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  installation of package ‘nlme’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Comment: Put this line `R_LIBS_USER="~/R/mylib"` in your `.Renviron` file where `/home/R/mylib` is the folder that you have write-permission

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020616/how-to-properly-set-up-the-library-directory-path-in-r

Comment: this is what i did before running R

Comment: helga@idelphonse-Lenovo-V110-15AST ~ $ /home/helga/R
bash: /home/helga/R: Is a directory
helga@idelphonse-Lenovo-V110-15AST ~ $ mkdir /home/helga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/mylib
helga@idelphonse-Lenovo-V110-15AST ~ $ R_LIBS_USER="~/helga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/mylib"

Comment: then after i tried to install the seqinr package i still got the same error

Comment: > install.packages()

Installing packages into ‘/home/helga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘ade4’

Comment: -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tests.c -o tests.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o ade4.so adesub.o divsub.o fourthcorner.o init.o phylog.o testamova.o testdim.o testrlq.o tests.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6:

Comment: ERROR: dependency ‘ade4’ is not available for package ‘seqinr’
* removing ‘/home/helga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/seqinr’

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/Rtmp8iH4u8/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages() :
  installation of package ‘ade4’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages() :
  installation of package ‘seqinr’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: where yould my packages actually go? How will I tell R to put them there cause it is saying not a writeable path.