# install package error. lib is unspecified

Tags: r

I am having the following problem:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Test/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/backports_1.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 101330 bytes (98 KB)
downloaded 98 KB
```

I consistently receive an error message stating that my lib is not specified. Despite attempting to "run as administrator" in R Studio, the settings always revert to the default location at users/Test/AppData…. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish, this is only a informational message, not an error. So it seems like package installation is working as intended but with an annoying message.

To get rid of it, you can try to set your default library path explicitely. Unless you have strong reasons to install to a custom directory, I would suggest you set it to the standard directory, in your case `C:/Users/Test/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3`

There are a number of questions addressing "How to set my default library" here on SO:

- [How do I change the default library path for R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages?rq=3)
- [How to properly set up the library directory/path in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020616/how-to-properly-set-up-the-library-directory-path-in-r)