# .libPaths(blah) does nothing

Tags: r

Apologies if someone has asked this before.  I've tried Googling and Googling, but no one seems to have reported quite this.  I'm trying to add a path to my `.libPaths`, but `.libPaths(new=blah)` doesn't seem to alter anything.  Here is my code:

```
packagedir = paste0(getwd(),'/extraRPackages/')
newLibPaths = c(packagedir,.libPaths())
print(newLibPaths)
.libPaths(newLibPaths)
print(.libPaths())
```

...here is the output from the first print (what I'm passing into `.libPaths`):

```
[1] "C:/Users/GCW/Dropbox/Mash share/Phil/R/mashdb/database/extraRPackages/"
[2] "C:/Users/GCW/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"                              
[3] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library"
```

... and the second print:

```
[1] "C:/Users/GCW/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library"
```

Why might my call to .libPaths(new=blah) do absolutely nothing??  I'm stumped!  I've tried it in RStudio and RPortable, but both give me the same output...  Any help v much appreciated...

(I know from reading other answers that there are "proper" ways to change the paths permanently, but this is something I want to be able to do dynamically in a rather unusual setup, and if .libPaths just did what I thought it would, I'd be done...)

EDIT: It was suggested that this might be a duplicate of this question [Changing R default library path using .libPaths in Rprofile.site fails to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399) -- but I don't think it is.  I read this question before posting my own -- but in this question, it says at the end that "if I start RStudio the .libPaths() command seems to work as it is supposed to" -- but it is precisely in RStudio that the command doesn't do anything for me (and this is where I want to use it, not in the RProfile.site file and not in any permanent way)....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work

Comment: Thanks for looking at this!  I've added an edit to explain why I think this is different.  Specifically, I want to be able to update my .libPaths as a one-off within some R code.  It's hacky, I know, but for this one application it will make my life a lot easier...

Comment: Oh, figured out my silly mistake.  Fixed (see below).  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ah I figured it out!  The folder name you pass to .libPaths(blah) should not end with a "/".  I changed the first line above to

```
packagedir = paste0(getwd(),'/extraRPackages')
```

...and all is well.  Apologies for the dumb question!

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if the directory you're trying to add to .libPaths doesn't exist yet.