# Cannot install Rcmdr, RcppEigen and Rccp not being put in correct folder

Tags: r, windows-10, rcpp

Im currently trying to install R 3.2.5 on an Asus Zenbook running Windows 10. No matter what I do, when I try to install Rcmdr to R

`package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\file24a01d367b67\RcppEigen’ to ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\RcppEigen’`

and

`package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\file24a0696e46c4\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library\Rcpp’`

Ive changed C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5 to be fully controllable by the user, and it still gets the same error

Comment: usually you would have your own R library for installed packages somewhere in your personal directories. If there is not already one create a directory soemthing like  `"C:/Users/username/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"`. Then `.libPaths(c(new.directroy.name,  .libPaths())) ` should let R know to use it. then try installing again. If this works, then see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19662905/2761575) how to let R know to always look for this library

Comment: Permission, permissions, permissions. Learn to use your chosen operating system.

Comment: Turns out my problem was installing the x32 version, once I installed the x64 version everything worked fine