# Create Graphs and Plots Using R in Microsoft R Server

Tags: r

I am going over 'Create Graphs and Plots Using R (Data Science End-to-End Walkthrough)' procedure.

Please check link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt629162.aspx

I have issue with step 'Create a Map Plot', when executing:

```
myplots <- rxExec(mapPlot, inDataSource, googMap, timesToRun = 1)  
plot(myplots[[1]][["myplot"]])
```

I am getting error:

```
Warning: namespace 'CompatibilityAPI' is not available and has been replaced 
by .GlobalEnv when processing object 'inputObject' 
======  DESKTOP-PHAA5KQ  ( process  1 ) has started run 
                                          at  2017-01-24 11:39:07.56  ====== 
Warning: namespace 'CompatibilityAPI' is not available and has been replaced 
by .GlobalEnv when processing object 'inputObject' 
Loading required package: ggplot2 
Loading required package: maps 

 # ATTENTION: maps v3.0 has an updated 'world' map.        # 
 # Many country borders and names have changed since 1990. # 
 # Type '?world' or 'news(package="maps")'. See README_v3. # 


Error in slot(from, what) : 
  no slot of name "maxColWidth" for this object of class "RxSqlServerData" 
Calls: source ... anyStrings -> validityMethod -> as -> asMethod -> slot 
Execution halted 
Error in rxCompleteClusterJob(hpcServerJob, consoleOutput, autoCleanup) : 
  No results available - final job state: failed
> plot(myplots[[1]][["myplot"]])
Error in plot(myplots[[1]][["myplot"]]) : object 'myplots' not found
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a version issue.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775573/how-to-use-rxexec-to-run-standard-r-remote) gave me some context. Your IDE or client may not be using the same version of R as R-Services.

Check the version of R in your IDE and R-Services using:

```
R.Version()
```

For R-Services, navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.YOUR_SERVER_NAME\R_SERVICES\bin then run R.exe as admin.

You might see that the versions are different. In my case I was running 3.3.2 in RStudio but have 3.2.2 in R-Services.

For RStudio, here's [how to use different versions of R.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R) Starting RStudio with the Control key held down allowed me to select the R-Services instance and run the code successfully.

You can also change your [default library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) so that whenever you open your IDE you're working with the server's version of R.

Answer (score 0):

In my case both R services and R studio had same version. And the error  message was ggplot2 is required by ggmap. For my solution I uninstalled both ggplot2 and ggmap, Closed R studio and reopened it with administrative rights.