# Loading package hosted at github

Tags: r, github

I have been using [Hilary Parker](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) instructions to create R packages and host them at Github. They work great as long as I work locally, which defeats the purpose.

When I import my packages in other computers, other than my own, library(my_package) results in it not being found in the system. The particular system I am trying it on is a Ubuntu 16.10 machine.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("lf-araujo/sempsychiatry", force=TRUE)
devtools::install("sempsychiatry")
library("sempsychiatry")
```

For testing you can try one of the functions:

```
dependencies(c("dplyr","memisc"))
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: check your libPaths?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work

Comment: Loading works for me.  Trying out `dependencies` throws an error `Error in ifelse(i %in% installed.packages(), library(i, character.only = TRUE),  : 
  replacement has length zero`. Are you sure you're using `i %in% installed.packages()` correctly? Shouldn't it be `installed.packages() %in% i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Adam Quek noted, you can run `print(.libPaths())` to see where all your libraries are stored, and check if yours is among them.

Your online github repository is sufficient to install your package.
Using `devtools::install_github("lf-araujo/sempsychiatry")` should do the trick (I can install and use your package this way).

Please note that before you install your package on a different machine first make sure you are in a new session and you removed any trace of the old package.

Tip:
1) As long as your `MWE.csv` is in your main folder and not under `/data` is it not installed/released when loading your package.
2) If you want to have some additional information about packages [this](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz) is a good read