# How to set up an alternative R package library in a writable location on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation

I'm having a problem installing some R packages on an Ubuntu OS. I've tried a number of suggested solutions in various blogs and SO answers but the problem persists.

The default location for installing packages is `'lib = "/usr/lib/R/library"'`

Using the commands

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite('affycoretools')
```

Fails because `'lib = "/usr/lib/R/library"'` is not a writable location for me (note that I do have sudo access). I therefore want these packages to be installed to this location which is writable:

```
lib='/home/b3053674/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2'
```

So the first thing I try is:

```
biocLite('affycoretools,lib=lib)
```

Which seems to work but now:

```
    library(affycoretools) 
    #try specifying location
    library(affycoretools,lib=lib)
    #try alternative keyword - just in case
    library(affycoretools,lib.loc=lib)
```

all fail with `there is no package called ‘affycoretools’`.

I then tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) which suggests that I create an `R_LIBS_USER` variable. I therefore used  `export R_LIBS_USER="/home/b3053674/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2"` and tried again but this seemed to do precisely nothing. I've also attempted to put this variable in a file in the home directory called `.Renviron` which also does nothing. I've tried giving the new library path to `R_LIBS` environment variable instead but again nothing. I've also tried a few other solutions regarding the `.libPaths()` and `.Library` function/variables but not joy...

I'm guessing this type of configuration is fairly routine to people who know R  but everything I try seems to fail so my question is: could anybody give me precise and clear instructions to setting up an alternative writable library for my bioconductor packages in R on an `Ubuntu 16.04.1` OS?

Comment: If you have sudo access, why don't you start R as sudo?

Comment: Just because I don't want to have to start R as root every time I want to  use R - hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need to start R as sudo just when you install packages. You can read from `/usr/lib`, so after installing the package, you can use it with any user.

Comment: Ah yes, Its a bit of an annoying way around but that will work for now. Thanks