# Launch separate RStudio session on a different port?

Tags: r, rstudio, rhel7, rstudio-server

I have a RStudio server running on port, say, 8787, which is then accessible by a web browser.

The problem is, if my colleague wants to use RStudio, I'll be disconnected as only one user can use the RStudio.

I'm looking for how can we launch another instance of RStudio session on a separate port number, say, 8989.

This should allow at least 2 different users to run 2 separate RStudio sessions on the same server.

To be clear, I'm on RStudio server free version. I'm not sure whether features like multiple sessions on different ports require paid license or not.

If it helps, I'm using RHEL7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a license for this. Even the free version of RStudio Server will allow you to run one session *per user*.

So you don't need to try to run multiple servers on multiple ports; just set up a regular Linux user account for your colleague on your server (using e.g. `adduser`), and they'll be able to log into RStudio and run their own R session.