# Error in clusplot.default: object 'spannel' not found

Tags: r, shiny

Recently I upgraded my linux server-deployed shiny app's R from 3.3.3 to 3.4.1, and now instead of cluster plots i'm getting this error.

Didn't change nothing else and can't access server to try and debug it. All I have now is an error message:

```
Warning: Error in clusplot.default: object 'spannel' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    104: clusplot.default
    103: clusplot
    102: eval
    101: eval
    100: withProgress
     99: renderPlot
     89: <reactive:plotObj>
     78: plotObj
     77: origRenderFunc
     76: output$KM_plot
      1: runApp
```

As far as I understand, `spannel` is a C function, I know nothing about C, unfortunately.

here is briefly how it looks in `server.R` file: `clusplot(KMData, KM$cluster)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R upgrade messed up your libraries that are bound to `shiny`, compare the output of `.libPaths()` so they are in the correct directory. Also make sure never to run **R** as `sudo` as running it as `root` might crash your entire box

Comment: Sorry I didn't delete the question:
I was getting a version of 'cluster' in R 3.4.1, but my cluster
has been installed with R < 3.4.0.
I deleted that version and got a newer version of 'cluster', which worked fine with R 3.4.1. Should I delete the question, by the way? Not sure what to do in such cases on SO.

Comment: its a common question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work/23061822