# Accessing libraries installed via RStudio from Jupyter Notebook with R Kernel -- avoiding conflicts

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, installation-package

I have been using R Studio through which I have installed a large number of R libraries to my system.  Recently I begun working through Jupyter Notebook with an R Kernel.  However I am facing 2 problems:

a) I can not access libraries I have already installed in my system -- such as dplyr

b) I can not reinstall these libraries from within Jupyter Notebook:

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
Installing package into 'C:/Install/R_LIBS'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependency 'tibble'

package 'tibble' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning message:
"cannot remove prior installation of package 'tibble'"
package 'dplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning message:
"cannot remove prior installation of package 'dplyr'"

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\akonstantinidis\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqUPKMw\downloaded_packages

library(dplyr)

Error in library(dplyr): there is no package called 'dplyr'
Traceback:

1. library(dplyr)
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

## Edit

As Alistaire very helpfully and kindly suggested in the comment below this post, I run the command .libPaths() from within RStudio and the from within Jupyter Notebook.

The results were the following:

**RStudio:**

```
"C:/Install/R_LIBS"    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Server/R_SERVER/library"
```

**Jupyter Notebook**

```
'C:/Install/R_LIBS' 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/R/library'
```

Then I changed the library paths so that:

```
.libPaths()
'C:/Install/R_LIBS' 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Server/R_SERVER/library' 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/R/library'
```

Nonetheless, when I tried to load the dplyr library I got the same error message:

```
library(dplyr)
Error in library(dplyr): there is no package called 'dplyr'
Traceback:

1. library(dplyr)
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)
```

Comment: I've always found packages show up regardless of what interface I use, but I'm not on Windows, so things are arranged a little differently. Regardless, I'd check where `.libPaths()` points for each interface; that's where R installs and looks for packages.

Comment: Thank you.  Please see edited post.

Comment: Go look at those directories and see where the packages are actually installed, then make the results of `.libPaths` look the same, either by using it to set the values or [by using environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662905/4497050), which seems to be the proper way on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me!  Please find in my post more info.