# h2o.init() setup not working - localhost

Tags: r, machine-learning

[image]

Trying to get h2o up and running but running into this error. Thought it was Java version, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm confused on what is wrong. I'm looking into the localhost problem, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and when I looked at the .out file I saw that h2o wasn't finding the library path. That was because my computer name had space. So there's two options: (1) change your user name ([Changing R default library path using .libPaths in Rprofile.site fails to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work)) or (2) change the library folder ([tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qm6thcW4eTM)).