# Pass .Renviron file location to R session?

Tags: r, linux

By default, R looks for a .Renviron file in the home directory (as explained e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785071).

In that .Renviron file, a custom package installation directory can be specified with `R_LIBS_USER=/some/path`.

Can I pass a custom .Renviron file to an CLI R session, i.e. something like below?

`R --environment=/my/custom/folder/.Renviron`

or

`Rscript --environment=/my/custom/folder/.Renviron`

to overwrite `~/.Renviron` (or if there's no .Renviron in the home directory at all).

Comment: Look at `?Renviron`. Basically you export the `R_ENVIRON` variable and open R.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nicola, I was able to open up an ad-hoc R session with a custom R_LIBS path like so. That was the initial idea, using an .Renviron file is not even necessary anymore.

```
export R_LIBS_USER=~/my/custom/folder/lib
R
```