# Is there a way to mix conda and native R?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, conda

I have found that even with the R package [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/index.html), sometimes I run into a problem where an R package in my environment won't load. Or, the R package may not be available in the conda channels I'm using.

However, if I install the R package natively with `install.packages`, R installs its own versions of many libraries I know I have already installed with conda.

Is there some combination of environment variables or some other way to ask R to fist check my conda library and then build against that?

I tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `conda/lib`, but that either did not reduce the problem or led to build errors.

Comment: You probably saw this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work Note what Paweł says: "The Rprofile solution does not work when clicking on a file to start RStudio because that changes the working directory away from the default working directory."

Comment: @RomanLuštrik--I had not seen that. Thanks. Conda I have found that conda does not recommend setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I am not familiar with `R_LIBS_USER` and what it does, so that will be a good place for me to start.