# Trying to add a new library directory

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using hosted RStudio on linux centos. When I try to install packages I get a non zero exit status error. I've already installed R-devel.

From reading the output to r console when trying to install packages it looks my user cannot access the default library path.

I read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) post about adding a new library directory and even making it the default one.

Within RStudio GUI, in the bottom right pane I created a new directory "mylibs".

I tried adding to libPaths() per the SO post:

```
.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "~/mylibs") )
```

Then I typed `.libPaths()`.

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4"
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"                               
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"
```

So it looked like that failed. I wondered if I had not specified the correct directory. So, in RStudio I typed `getwd()` which shows that I'm in `"/home/rstudio"`. So, I then tried: `.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "~/home/rstudio/mylibs") )`

However, when I checked `.libPaths()` there was no change, the same 3 shown above.

How can I add mylibs dir to .libPaths() so that I can download and install packages?

Comment: Does the "~/mylibs" folder actually exist. The `.libPaths()` function won't add a folder if it doesn't exist. Also, just to be clear, the `~` will expand to your home directory (not the current working directory). If the folder you are trying to specify is not in your home directory, you don't need that part. It would be better to use a fully qualified path (start with "/").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.libPaths()` *prepends* as order is from left to right.  On this CentOS machine:

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/USER/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib64/R/library"                             "/usr/share/R/library"  
R>
R> .libPaths("/tmp")   # adding in session
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/tmp"                  "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib64/R/library"  "/usr/share/R/library"         
R>
```

You can govern what gets in there via the different "dot" files read at startup, ie `.Renviron`, `.Rprofile` and more.  See `help(Startup)` for all the gory details.

*Edit:* Regarding @MtFlick's comment:

```
R> .libPaths("/DoesNotExist")
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib64/R/library"   
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"         
R>
```

Comment: I don't think the problem was where the folder was added in the list; the problem seems to be it wasn't added at all. I think that's a different issue.

Comment: That happens when the directory does not exist.