# Change default loading of `shiny` to specific `.libPaths()` on ShinyServer

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

## Problem

I'm deploying a Shiny App on a shiny server maintained by my university, and there are many `.libPaths()` that contain different versions of packages.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/zeolite/rpauloo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4"
[2] "/nfs/admin/software/xenial/system-gcc/R_libs"      
[3] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                     
[4] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                           
[5] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

When my shiny app boots up, `shiny` is loaded by default from `.libPaths()[2]`, which then imports `R6` **V.2.2.1**, also from this path.

## However, my code depends on `R6` **>= V.2.2.2**, which I have in `.libPaths()[1].`

It would be simple enough to have my SysAdmin update `R6` in `.libPaths()[2]`, but they cannot because other people's apps depend on the libraries on that path, and we don't want to break those.

---

## I've tried:

1. detaching `R6` and loading it from `.libPaths()[1]`

   ```
   detach("package:R6", unload=TRUE, force = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
   library(R6, lib.loc = "/zeolite/rpauloo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4")
   ```
2. detaching `shiny` and loading it from `.libPaths()[1]`

   ```
   detach("package:shiny", unload=TRUE, force = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
   library(shiny, lib.loc = "/zeolite/rpauloo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4")
   ```
3. setting my `.libPaths()` from the start in the `global.R` file to only include the path I want.

   ```
   .libPaths(.libPaths()[1])
   ```
4. adding an `etc` folder under `"/zeolite/rpauloo/R"` that contains the following `Rprofile.site` file ([advice from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work)):

   ```
   .First <- function(){
     .libPaths("/zeolite/rpauloo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4")
   }
   ```

None of these approaches work. Why?

1. `R6` is an attached package, so it can't be unloaded.
2. not sure why unloading/reloading shiny doesn't work
3. Shiny Server loads `shiny` from `.libPaths()[2]` to begin with, before the `global.R` file is sourced, so setting `libPaths()` doesn't help.
4. the `Rprofile.site` file is probably in the wrong directory, but putting it in an admin directory will mess with other apps

---

## Question

#### How can I configure my shiny app to load `shiny` from a specific `.libPath` on startup?

Or have I mis-conceptualized the problem? Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Is the shiny server running as its own user? I believe you can alter the `.libPaths()`  in `global.R` probably - however this still seems a bit hacky. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work Also maybe https://kb.iu.edu/d/avks?

Comment: @zacdav, thanks for taking a look. I've updated my question to reflect this. The problem is that when I update my `.libPaths()` in `global.R` to only include the ones I want, Shiny Server has already loaded `shiny`, and attached the old version of `R6`. I'm not sure what you mean by "running as its own user".

Comment: The shiny server will be running on a server as a specific user, I believe that this dictates permissions and where it looks for packages by default. So one solution would be to have shiny server running for each user and each user can then maintain the packages as they wish - bit of a nightmare for someone managing it though. Additionally, `Global.R` is run before the server has initialised (at least I thought it was), so if the first line was updating `.libPaths` i'm surprised it didn't work.

Comment: @zacdav, yeah I also thought `.libPaths(.libPaths()[1])` at the start of the `global.R` file would also work, but the error I get still indicates that shiny is loaded from `.libPaths()[2]` (I can tell because the version number). Maybe some `.Rprofile` or `Rprofile.site` file is running first and kick-starting this chain? I've updated the list of things I've tried.

Comment: Does the user that the shiny server is running as have read/write access to those paths?

Comment: I have read/write access to all paths but the admin's, which is `.libPaths()[2]`.

Comment: But what I'm saying is that the server doesn't run as if it was you, but as if it was another user. So if the user the shiny server is, is not you, it needs the correct permissions.