# Error on Rcpp::depends when using sourceCpp and RcppArmadillo

Tags: rcpp

The code can run through on my desktop. I tried to run it on a server  and got error 
`Error: Package 'RcppArmadillo' referenced from Rcpp::depends in source file is not available.` I wonder if something wrong when I installed the packages but I have no idea how to fix it.

The R script is like this

```
> library(Rcpp,lib="~/R_libs")
> library(RcppArmadillo,lib="~/R_libs")
> library(gtools,lib="~/R_libs")
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/Test/probit2.cpp')
Error: Package 'RcppArmadillo' referenced from Rcpp::depends in source 
file probit2.cpp is not available.`
```

And the cpp file begins with this

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to extend R’s library path, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work

Comment: "What Ralf said" -- set either `.libPaths()` more permanently, or equivalently one of the environment variables. You tell all the `library()` commands _explicitly_ but assume `sourceCpp()` knows magically by itself.  It does not, and you need to help it. See `help(Startup)` for many options.

Comment: Got it, I set the R_LIBS to my library folder and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: How about adding your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments above, I solved this by setting this from the terminal:

```
export R_LIBS="~/myRlib"
Rscript myscript.r
```

I could also set `.libPaths("~/myRlib")` in the R script.