# Don't use R system library

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to use a linux server with R installed. Apparently the R system library has old versions of non-base packages installed like dplyr and testthat. 
Because i don't have permission to edit the system library, i'm unable to update the packages.

My plan is to only use a user library, so I can controll the package versions myself. However i'm unable to remove the `"/usr/lib64/R/library"` folder from `.libPaths()`. I tried changing the environment variables `R_LIBS_SITE` and `R_LIBS` with the `.Renviron` and `.Rprofile` files to a different folder, but the `/usr/lib64/R/library` folder will always be present. Removing it with the command `.libPaths(.libPaths()[1:2])` doesn't work either.

Is there a way to remove the system library from `.libPaths()`, so I'm not depending on the update policy of the server admin?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work .

Comment: Thanks for the link, it has valuable information. I can't find a way to remove the system library from .liPaths(), however

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the system library, because that's where the base packages live.  They can't be installed anywhere else, and R won't work without them.

Best would be for you to get your sysadmin to update the system library.  Those obsolete packages probably contain bugs.

If you can't do that, then run `update.packages(instlib = "local")` to install all the latest versions in the library named `"local"`.  (Substitute your own local lib name, of course.)  This requires all your users to specify `.libPaths("local")` when they start, and some will likely forget, so it's not as good.

It might be easiest for you to just install a full copy of R in your own account.  Then you'll have control of things, and anyone using your copy will get your library.

(There's a new release (3.5.3) coming in ten days; you might wait for that, or install one of the betas or RCs, which should be available now, then update again when the final release arrives.)

Comment: I added another alternative, using `update.packages()`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works to use

```
 .libPaths(.libPaths()[2:1])
```

This will still search the system library, but only *after* it searches my personal library, so if I have a newer version,  it uses that. **Note:** I used `.libPaths()[2:1]` not `.libPaths()[1:2]`

Comment: When I try to install a package the dependecies will not be installed when it's already in the system library, the install will fail with this error:
`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘covr’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'covr', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package ‘lazyeval’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version`

Comment: Have you tried installing the dependencies using `install.packages(pkgs, lib=MyLib` ?

Comment: I tried installing all dependencies separately, and when I do this, it'll work. However, my aim is to make a generic and automated solution, so other users won't need to install all dependencies by hand.

Comment: @G5W:  Your answer doesn't do what you say it does.  If you just have one path in your call to `.libPaths()`, it will be searched first, then the system library.  If you have two, those two will be searched in the order you specify, and then the system library will be searched:  but only if it wasn't one of the two.  So your recipe will not force the system library to be searched second.  It is *normally* searched second, but your recipe might make it be searched first.