# How to specify a Conda env path to install all libraries in R

Tags: r, libraries

I have a set of libraries needed to be installed for different users, how to specify it in `.libPath()` and in `install.packages()`?
Otherwise, by default, it is going to global space and throwing the error (`is not writable`) message when I try it within an `RScript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your default `.libPath()` by giving the first entry of libPath another path value

```
new_path <- "./Desktop"
.libPath(new_path)
```

or simply `.libPath("./Desktop")`

And it got changed

you can check it by using

`libPath()`

Explanation: `install.packages()` is using the first value of `.libPath()` as default. Also if you don't want to change the default you can also using `install.packages(pkg, lib="~/Desktop")`. Just edit it for your anaconda path.

Also see this old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work).
You can also append an old library to a new one by following this

Comment: What if I need to run the whole thing as Rscript on as a command line argument? Say, I would like to give all these in a .R file?

Comment: @user1017373 i don't understand this question. This is normal R syntax, just put it in your R file or the command line.