# Versioning problem with R on mac os 10.14.5

Tags: r, rstudio

All of a sudden my R installation is giving me trouble although I havent upgraded R recently and it worked perfectly about a week ago. When I try to load tidyverse packages, dplyr for instance, I get the following error msg:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tidyselect/libs/tidyselect.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tidyselect/libs/tidyselect.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tidyselect/libs/tidyselect.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Seeing that there is a mix-up between Version 3.6 and 3.5 I guess it can be rectified somehow by setting a path to the correct verion, but I am uncertain how I can do it and I have no clue as to how this happened since everything has worked allright without any new R installations recently.

Comment: You can check the library paths with `.libPaths()`. Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) help?

Comment: The libpaths pointed to 3.6. I updated xcode without any use. But after I did a complete restart of everything and did update.packages(repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', ask=FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE) it now works again. I have no idea why...