# R - Problems with German umlauts in library path

Tags: r, rstudio

I can't load any packages in R since the upgrade to R 4.0. Problem is an umlaut in my Windows username. 
I can install packages without any problems, but I can't load them.
For example:

```
> install.packages("pracma")
#...
# Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Völker/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
#...
> library(pracma)
#Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘pracma’ in runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package):
# can't open file 'C:/Users/VÃ¶lkerM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/pracma/R/pracma.rdb': No such file or directory
```

The files are there so the problem is just the umlaut in "Völker". 
I tried in RStudio and RGUI, same error. I had no Problem before updating R to 4.0 (but unfortunately I need R 4.0).

I coudn't find a solution yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your default file installation path until the R developers get this bug fixed. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662905/3072826) does a good job of explaining some options.