# Impossible to use R

Tags: r

Im having trouble to install any package after downloading the last R update. The errors always look like this:

ERROR: dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘glue’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘tidyselect’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tidyselect’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status

Also it appears an error such as this:

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘backports’

Anyone has any idea how i can change this?

Comment: That means you have to install those packages one by one. I had that problem and when I checked `.libPaths()` I realized I was installing in a new directory where none of those packages were to be found (and any other package). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) on how to fix the libs path.

Comment: Which R version (`R.version()`) do you use? Perhaps its this [bug](https://github.com/r-lib/backports/issues/31)...