# How to fix an R environment variable in Windows 10

Tags: r, renv

I have a student with a Windows 10 machine that has a bad path set for the R_LIBS_USER variable.  I went into the R program directory and edited .Rprofile to set to R_LIBS_USER = "". That works until I am in a project using the `renv` package.  `renv` apparently uses that variable and it brings the brings the bad path back.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) and tried to find the variable it in Control Panel (System Properties -> Advanced system properties -> Environment Variables -> User Variables) but I didn't see the key to delete.

I did a full reinstall of R and the problem is still here.... help.

How can I find/erase that bad path is stored in Windows?

Comment: Environment variables are set first in `.Renviron`.  See `?Startup` for the details of how that file is found.

Comment: and if you don't see a key to delete in the env var control panel, can you set it to "nothing"? (I haven't tried ... does windows/R deal gracefully with an empty `R_LIBS_USER`?)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have set it to be "" in the .Renviron file.  For better or worse {renv} is finding it. I need a Windows maven to help me kill it in the OS.