# Migrate all R packages to another directory permanently

Tags: r, rstudio, libraries

Currently the packages I installed in R are stored in /Mydocuments/R/win-library. However, I got some problems with that because it´s a network drive and I would prefer to move all existing packages and the ones I will install in the future to a local drive.

Is there an easy and clean way to migrate all those packages to a new location without having to reinstall R and RStudio from scratch?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work